# CYK result de-transformation

Tags: parsers, natural-language-processing

Suppose we have a rules derived from a treebank.
And in order to get a syntax tree of a given sentence we use the cyk algorithm.
In order to use the cyk we should convert the rules into chomsky normal form,
Such that all of my rules are A -> B C or A -> a (A,B,C are non-terminals and a is a terminal).
From the cyk we get the most probable tree, constituted from the cnf rules.
But what if we want to de-transform the tree to be constituted from the original rules?
We can expand very easily the Binary rules into the original.
But what about unit productions? for example; A->B->a transformed into A->a in cnf, how do we get the original unary rules path A->B->a?
Any ideas will be helpful.

Comment: This modification of the algorithm avoids full CNF transformation, yet has comparable simplicity: https://www.informaticadidactica.de/index.php?page=LangeLeiss2009

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can recover a unit production, unless (and this is probably the common case) the unit production is unambiguous. If there is only one derivation from a non-terminal to a particular terminal -- and it should be easy to figure that out while you are doing the transformation to CNF -- then you can record that derivation and reinsert it when you find the collapsed derivation in the CYK parse.